# The generic off-topic flag reason has different wording in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, android-app

In the Android app, when flagging a question as off-topic, a generic option appears in the list of off-topic reasons, at the next-to-last position before migration or at the last position if migration is impossible. The formulation of this option is “This question does not appear to be about $TOPIC within the scope defined in the help center”.

That's not bad, but the website has different wording: “Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with $TOPIC)”. The app should use the same wording as the website.

Example:

[image: mobile] vs [image: website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in prod.

The solution is described here: [Double flag bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251535/double-flag-bug/272549#272549)

Comment: Little bug? I just tried and the app crashes when opening the flag dialog (when it's already displayed the title but there's still only a small box without options and there's a “busy” animation). The crash is only on sites where I don't have the close privilege.

Comment: @Gilles Looks like that screen is pretty crash-prone.  Seeing a surge in crashes which could be me or could just be because people are excitedly testing my fix. :/ Will investigate.

Comment: @Gilles should be fixed. Had a NPE on the API because migration doesn't have a OffTopicReason. App will probably still crash if you try flagging with no network connection though. 