# Flagging bug in app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I tried to flag a question as belonging here instead of meta SO. I tried this from the app, but I got this:
[image]
(This is other reason->off topic.) There is no "move to meta stack exchange" option like I expected, and the first and last options are duplicates.

Comment: (Since there's a closevote here, I remark that this bug  is not SO-specific).

Comment: Close voter: app questions belongs here on MSE **please do not close them**!

Comment: Are you still seeing this on any sites?  I've tried a few sites and they appear to match, and the server code seems the same for both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known inconsistency between close reason formulations on the SE sites and in the apps. It was reported for Android app already:  [The generic off-topic flag reason has different wording in the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240390/) but since your report is about iOS app, it's not a 100% duplicate. (Although the underlying issue might be in the API.)

Let's compare to the off-topic closeflag reasons on the site itself:

[image]

As you can see, the "blatant" reason (which, frankly, is somewhat redundant to begin with) does not correctly render in the app. I recall that *blatantly off-topic* was added to all sites relatively recently, after the app launch. This may be the reason for the bug.

Comment: Right, 'blatant' is the flagging version of 'closing as other' when voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option on the web interface for Meta Stack Overflow site either. The flagging menu reflects the actual options available through the web interface.

You'll have to flag a post with the *Other* option (first screen) and request a moderator migrates such posts.

As for the top reason re-appearing at the bottom, that does look like a bug. When you have enough reputation, you get to fill in a custom *off-topic because* reason that would appear in that last slot, but if you don't yet then nothing should be listed there.

Comment: I was unaware of that, thanks. However, the duplicated option definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: @kittycat3141: the last option normally is an 'other' closing reason (when you have enough reputation), so it does look like that is a bug.

Comment: @kittycat3141 It is not a bug. Only users without full close voting privileges see that last option. Users with full privileges instead have the option to enter in a custom message for why it is off-topic. On Meta Stack Overflow, we explicitly copied that into a custom close reason so users could easily select a "blatantly off-topic" sort of reason without having to type something in. So, anyone who has to flag for closure will always see a duplicated close reason. This *only* happens on a meta site where they have copied that custom reason. Meta Stack Exchange also does this.

Comment: @animuson Is there a difference in what the first and last options in the screenshot do? If so, the difference needs to be explained, otherwise the last option is pointless because it's exactly the same as the first option.

Comment: @kittycat3141 No. A flag for closure doesn't affect actual close votes in any way, only sends it to the Close Votes queue. So it does not matter at all which one you use.

Comment: @animuson so why show two then? No *other* option was filled out here, right?

Comment: @animuson It matters a little bit, because the reviewers in the Close queue will be told *This question has been flagged as: off-topic (more)* and the  reason selected by the flagger will be shown if they click (more).

Answer (score 0):

The double flag bug is fixed in prod as described here:  [Double flag bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251535/double-flag-bug/272549)

As Martjin mentioned, the lack of a migration option is reflecting what's available for that question on the web.