# Double flag bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

iOS SEß 1.2.2.200

Since when did SE let you double flag?

[image: !]

There are two same flags in here.

Is it possible to be fixed?

Comment: No repro, I see "Other" as the last option. What question were you flagging?

Comment: @Shadow Before that, how do I check my flags?

Comment: Profile --> activity --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/Os06R.png (it's a link :)) oh, and I fear it's not possible via the app.

Comment: @Shadow Okey lemme check

Comment: @Shadow Great! 404!

Comment: huh? where 404? What exactly did you do?

Comment: @Shadow I clicked into helpful flags then clicked the question with this bug. It is a question with the title "Simple Interest" which belongs to MathsSE

Comment: So it means the question is deleted. Still a weird bug, but an edge case since you should not be able to see deleted questions in the app to begin with. It got deleted while you were viewing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/837/discussion-between-shadow-wizard-and-arceusmaster0493).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The very last option in the list is meant to be dynamic. Users without full vote-to-close privileges (under 3k reputation) see a standard "blatantly off-topic" close reason there, whereas users with full vote-to-close privileges (over 3k reputation) don't. Instead, they see a "custom" off-topic reason that prompts them to explain why they think the question is off-topic.

However, Meta is a special case that frequently gets a *lot* of random crap that doesn't belong here, and making users with full vote-to-close privileges always have to type in a custom reason is just irritating and results in a lot of not-so-constructive comments getting posted on them because no one *wants* to type something in for some of the stuff that ends up here.

The easiest solution: just copy-paste the default off-topic reason into another custom off-topic reason. Users with full privileges will see a standard "blatantly off-topic" style option *and* the standard "enter a custom reason" option, at the cost of under-privileged users seeing a duplicated reason that doesn't really cause any problems.

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in prod.

This is related to [Custom close votes broken in iOS app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295336/custom-close-votes-broken-in-ios-app/314201).  There's logic when building flags to insert a "blatantly off-topic" close reason for users who can't cast a close vote and insert "This question does not appear to be..." for sites with no custom close reasons.

The two paths both manifest as the default off topic reason in the model and the text to display gets sorted out on rendering.  The API was missing the rendering logic so it was incorrectly displaying "This question does not appear to be...".  That just so happens to be popular text to add as the last custom close reason, hence the duplication.