# Remove one of the off-topic close reasons

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons, off-topic

Here on MSE, there are two close reasons within "off-topic" that mean *exactly* the same thing. This:

> This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.

and this:

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with the software that powers the Stack Exchange network)

Should one of these be removed?

Comment: [Animuson's reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251544/282094) for the duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter of those two close reasons is there because you're not looking at the close vote dialog. Since you don't yet have the close vote privilege, you're looking at the close *flag* dialog, which has this distinct difference. Instead of the "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)" option that appears in the close *vote* dialog, you see the "Blatantly off-topic" option.

TL;DR: there is no <s>spoon</s> close reason.

Answer (score 3):

The second reason there is the generic off-topic reason which is present on every site in the network. It is not shown to people with the close vote privilege, who can only see the first.

It's less than ideal to have both, but it would probably take developer time to allow the second reason to be disabled on individual sites, and there are much bigger priorities for the devs to be working on.

Comment: "Bigger priorities"... like?