# What is the difference between these two off-topic flags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I flag a post, there are two very similar options in the off-topic list.
[image]

I am running version 1.0.57 of the Android app; Android version 4.1.2 (Jellybean). 

Is this supposed to happen? If so, what is the difference between them?

Comment: I think the last one is someone's (custom) close reason.

Comment: @PatrickHofman How does that work? I have not configured any custom close reasons.

Comment: The custom close reason someone entered when *he* voted to close.

Comment: Why should it show up for me?

Comment: Eh, you are right. You are not voting to close, you are flagging. My bad.

Comment: It took me quite a while to see your arrows... Don't you know that freehand ***must*** be red?

Comment: @nicael Oops, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is one of the off-topic close reasons set by moderators.

The second one is the generic off-topic flag reason which [is worded differently on the website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240390/the-generic-off-topic-flag-reason-has-different-wording-in-the-android-app): “Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with $TOPIC)”. This reason only appears in the flag dialog, close voters instead get “Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)”.

See also [the same bug report on Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/duplicate-entry-in-off-topic-list-in-the-android-app).

The best solution would be to reintroduce the “off-topic” close reason, as opposed to its current inconsistent incarnation where depending on whether you're flagging or closing, you get different options, and sites only have a generic off-topic reason for closing if one is set by a moderator.