# Is there a difference between these two flagging reasons or is this a bug?

Tags: support, bug, flags, flag-reasons

When flagging a post as **needs improvement** because of **a community-specific reason**, I get a list of reasons to choose from. Two of those reasons (given below) seem to imply the same thing.

> This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the
> Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.

> Blatantly off-topic
>
> *This question has nothing to do with the software
> that powers the Stack Exchange network.*

A [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250329/771581) has been asked before, but that was about the bug being in the SE app whereas I see it in the mobile version (as well as the desktop version) of the site. Moreover, the bug above has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

So, do the two reasons imply different things (in that case, please explain to me the difference)? Or is this a bug?